# SipManager missing methods

Tags: java, android, sip

I am currently working in a project that uses the Android SIP API but it doesn't register to the network. I've debugged and looked for sample code on the web and it seems my code is OK. So I looked deeper into the code at SipManager class and some of the methods and variable types appear to be non-existent, I'm uploading a screenshot so you get to take a look.

[image: cannot find symbol]

ISipService isn't the only object class that it cannot find, but I believe it could be the origin of all.
Do any of you know how can I figure it out?

Other objects that set off the warning:

[image: setRegistrationListener()]

[image: open()]

[image]

Any help is really appreciated
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using the I(Classes) at all. These are internal to the android framework and **not** meant to be used by applications and are also **never** exposed via the Android SDK, there is a reason @hide is used :) .

You preferably should use the public APIs as provided by the Android SDK @ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html

Comment: I don't. ISipService is a class that is used by SipManager I can't modify it.. The problem is that even though it is content of the SIP libraries it appears to not exist, so how can I make Studio to recognize the class?